# How to properly expand a list with certain numerical elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerics, fitting

There is a list with 19 elements `` a={0.500074`, 0.502676`, 0.510451`, 0.507502`, 0.52768`, 0.625164`,    0.935248`, 1.826161`, 3.845598`, 8.293859`, 18.014295`, 39.20736`,    85.3836`, 185.975252`, 405.095196`, 882.399269`, 1922.095421`,    4186.829292`, 9120.018288`} ``

The elements in the list are written according to a certain rule that I don't know. I would like to expand this list in both directions like here `` anew={... a, b, c, 0.500074`, 0.502676`, 0.510451`, 0.507502`, 0.52768`, 0.625164`,    0.935248`, 1.826161`, 3.845598`, 8.293859`, 18.014295`, 39.20736`,    85.3836`, 185.975252`, 405.095196`, 882.399269`, 1922.095421`,    4186.829292`, 9120.018288`, d, e, f ...} `` where `...a, b, c` and  `d, e, f...` are elements which fit the general rule.

How to find this rule and write down additional elements (or just find the most suitable elements)?

All elements should be a positive

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a={0.500074`, 0.502676`, 0.510451`, 0.507502`, 0.52768`, 0.625164`,    0.935248`, 1.826161`, 3.845598`, 8.293859`, 18.014295`, 39.20736`,    85.3836`, 185.975252`, 405.095196`, 882.399269`, 1922.095421`,    4186.829292`, 9120.018288`};
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the ratio of 2 consecutive elements:

```
a = {0.026284, 0.057253, 0.124713, 0.271658, 0.591744, 1.288974, 
   2.807725, 6.115966, 13.322188, 29.019243, 63.211573, 137.691494, 
   299.928425, 653.323290, 1423.110603, 3099.910594, 6752.423650};

Divide @@@ Partition[a, 2, 1]

{0.459085, 0.459078, 0.459081, 0.45908, 0.459081, 0.459081, 0.459081, \
0.459081, 0.459081, 0.459081, 0.459081, 0.459081, 0.459081, 0.459081, \
0.459081, 0.459081}
```

Therefore, each element is the predecessor times 1/0.459081= 2.17826. The continuation of 4 elelemnts to the left is, starting with a[1]]:

```
Reverse@NestList[0.4590811717341696` # &, a[[1]], 5]

{0.000535968, 0.00116748, 0.00254308, 0.0055395, 0.0120665, 0.026284}
```

and the continuation to the right starting with a[[-1]]:

```
NestList[1/0.4590811717341696` # &, a[[-1]], 5]

{6752.42, 14708.6, 32039.1, 69789.7, 152020., 331140.}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm, so sorry I gave a not very convenient sequence in the example. A better example is the following sequence: ```a = {0.500074`, 0.502676`, 0.510451`, 0.507502`, 0.52768`, 0.625164`, 
  0.935248`, 1.826161`, 3.845598`, 8.293859`, 18.014295`, 39.20736`, 
  85.3836`, 185.975252`, 405.095196`, 882.399269`, 1922.095421`, 
  4186.829292`, 9120.018288`}```

Comment: Now if we use your construction ```Divide @@@ Partition[a, 2, 1]``` will be returned next list of coefficients: ```{0.994824, 0.984768, 1.00581, 0.961761, 0.844067, 0.668447, 0.512139,0.47487, 0.463668, 0.460404, 0.459462, 0.459191, 0.459113, 0.45909, 0.459084, 0.459082, 0.459081, 0.459081}```, which are not the same. In the description of the task I have just changed of the list. I have many similar lists, each of which I need to correctly expand.

Comment: Is the creation rule for every list different? It is impossible to give a general answer if  the rule changes from list to list.. It is better, if you explain your problem, so that a rule may  be guessed.

Comment: Yes the rule is different for every list, because each list describes well the ground state of different Hamiltonians that differ in numerical coefficients in the third and fourth terms (Hamiltonian from here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284679/how-to-expand-the-existing-basis-set-so-that-it-becomes-more-complete).

Comment: But these parameters are not enough to describe the excited states, in order for the excited states to be correctly described, more parameters are needed, so I need to properly expand the lists.

Comment: I tried to use ```Interpolation``` and then get the extrapolated values of the coefficients. But Mathematica gives incorrect values on the left of the list, for some reason the function starts to increase when the argument decreases, but from the existing dependency it can be seen that it should decrease.

Comment: Interpolation fits a polynomial between succesive points and eventually extrapolates these plynomials at the beginning and end. Therefore "Interpolation" does not know about any rules.  What you could try is to fit a polynomial to the first/last n points and extrapolate these and check how these behave.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please demonstrate it (to fit a polynomial to the first/last n points and extrapolate these and check how these behave)

Comment: I tried it, but polynomials do not work well. But make a "ListLogPlot" that may tell you how to extrapolate.